# Reverting to an earlier version of Microsoft Office Home & Business 2016 (Retail)

Tags: microsoft-office

I am using the Office 2016 Deployment Tool in an attempt to download an earlier version of Office Home and Business 2016 (retail).

Here is the configuration.xml file that I have edited to my needs:

{ `<Configuration>
      <Add SourcePath="C:\Program Files\Office 2016 Revert
           OfficeClientEdition="64"
           Channel="Broad"
           Version="16.0.11727.20222"
      <Product ID="HomeBusinessRetail"
           <Language ID="en-us"
      </Product>
      </Add>
</Configuration>`}

When I run the command: setup.exe /download configuration.xml, the Office 2016 Revert directory is created, but no data is downloaded.

I have also checked out the Office Customization Tool (http://config.office.com), but it does not even give me the option for Home and Business. When I try to import my configuration.xml file, I get the notification that the import was successful, but some options could not be read (Product ID).

How can I revert my Office Home and Business 2016 (Retail) to an earlier version? 16.0.11727.20222 or earlier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your SourcePath is local path: "C:\Program Files\Office 2016 Revert”, I think you can delete this element. 
The Version 16.0.11727.20222 is for Office 365, not Office 2016 Home and Business.
Try the following configuration.xml:

```
 <Configuration>
  <Add OfficeClientEdition="64">
  <Product ID="HomeBusinessRetail">
       <Language ID="en-us" />
  </Product>
  </Add>
 <Configuration>
```